# How to reword a commit starting with a hashmark using git rebase?

Tags: git

I have made a commit with just `WIP` and now I would like to reword it to `#123456 - my message here`, where `#123456` is the number of the issue.

Since I've made other commits since then, my only option is to use `git rebase` and reword from there, but the hashmark is seen as a comment on the text editor.

Is there a way to do this without changing the comment symbol for the entire project?

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options:

- `core.commentChar` defines the character that is to be used for comments in commit messages.  You can change it for this clone with `git config`, do the commit, and then change it back, or override it just for this one `git commit` command; see below.
- `commit.cleanup` determines *how* a commit message is "cleaned" of commentary and other fluff: you can set this to `whitespace` or `verbatim`.  Again, you can do this temporarily for just one command.
- `-m` and `-F` options supply messages (as literal text, or via files) that are treated as if you used the `verbatim` cleanup option.

Of course your case is `git rebase -i` and `edit`, so I'd stick with `commit.cleanup` here: run `git -c commit.cleanup=verbatim rebase -i`.  I have not actually tested this, but it should do the trick.

Comment: I tried doing this, adding `HEAD~5`, but trying to `reword` it gives me some weird merge related error. Also, it shows way more than the last 5 commits for some reason.
Not adding `HEAD~5` opens nano with a weird "noop" commit, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: That's a completely different problem: you have a merge as your most recent commit. Rebase normally discards merges; add `--rebase-merges` to make `git rebase` re-*perform* a merge; and in general it's a bad idea to rebase if you have a merge commit in your history.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the quickest way, but you could (from a clean working tree)

```
# point a new branch at the faulty commit
git checkout -b repairBranch <yourBadCommit>

# amend the message
git commit --amend -m "#123456 - your message here"

# then finally bring copies of the later commits
git cherry-pick <yourBadCommit>..<yourOriginalBranch>
```

Then finally if the result is what you wanted, just reset your original branch on the new one with `git reset --hard repairBranch` (to be executed from your original branch, on a clean tree)

Comment: The cherry-pick makes me create a new commit after a merge conflict and it doesn't seen to get all later commits, which I've noticed after running a diff.

Comment: Which is odd, since `diff` doesn't tell you anything about commits, it compares trees and outputs code changes. And even if the later commits contain merge commits with resolved conflicts, it would have behaved the same way with a rebase (which is, under the hood, in fact doing a series of cherry-picks like we did here)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is that code that I know to belong to later commits is showing up in the diff.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use git rebase -i HEAD~N, where N is the number of commits from the most recent commit that you want to include in the interactive rebase. This will open a text editor showing a list of the commits that you specified. You can then change the pick command at the beginning of the line for the commit that you want to modify to reword.

For example, if you want to modify the commit that you made immediately before the most recent commit, you would run git rebase -i HEAD~2. This would open a text editor showing the two most recent commits, and you could change the pick command for the commit that you want to modify to reword.

When you save and exit the text editor, git will apply the interactive rebase and open a new text editor for you to modify the commit message for the commit that you selected. You can then modify the commit message to include the issue number, using the format #123456 - my message here.

After you save and exit the text editor, git will continue with the interactive rebase, applying any other changes that you specified. When the rebase is complete, your commit message will be updated with the issue number included.

Comment: The problem of OP being that rewording to `#123456 - my message here` in editor has the unwanted effect of skipping the new comment altogether, since `#` is the commenting char.